# How to make ps command to show user, PID, terminal, CMD

Tags: shell, unix

I need to use command that shows all processes related to terminal. Ps -a looks good except that there is no username printed. This command prints:

> ```
>   PID TTY         TIME   CMD
>   26969 pts/34      0:00 man
>   27636 pts/2       0:00 awk
>   25215 pts/35      0:00 bash
> ```

I would like it to be similar to this:

> ```
>   PID   TTY         TIME CMD  USER  
>   26969 pts/34      0:00 man  name
>   27636 pts/2       0:00 awk  name
>   25215 pts/35      0:00 bash name
> ```

Columns order does not matter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
ps a -o pid,tty,etime,cmd,user
```

From `ps` manual:

> **SIMPLE PROCESS SELECTION**
>
> ```
>    a    ... An alternate description is that this option causes ps to list all processes with a terminal (tty), or to list all processes
> ```
>
> when used together with the x option.
>
> **STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS**
>
> ```
>    Here are the different keywords that may be used to control the output format (e.g. with option -o) or to sort the selected processes
> ```
>
> with the GNU-style --sort
>          option.
>
> ```
>    For example:  ps -eo pid,user,args --sort user
> ```

Comment: Even though some of these keywords like "tt" does not work (it should be tty I guess) I get the point now. But how to use it with -a option? Because this shows all processes even with value of terminal like "?" which means that the process has no controlling terminal. I could use grep but there should be a solution with "-a" option in ps command

Comment: It says -o option is illegal. I have found my solution: ps -af

Comment: Different `ps` versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that ps -af works the way I want